# I'm not able to redirect the URL to a different webpage after submiting form values

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, dhtml

Hello Webmasters iam trying to redirect the webpage to a different URL/webpage after submitting the form elements ...i tried many ways but could not fix it...  please check the codes below that i have tried so far...

```
<?php
if(isset($_REQUEST['down'])){
    header("header("location: domainpath/kothi.html");
}
?>    
<html> 
<body>
    <form action="glitter.php" method="post">
        <input type="radio" name="font" value="fonts/darkcrystaloutline.ttf"/> 
        <input type="radio" name="font" value="fonts/darkcrystalout.ttf"/>
    </form> 
</body> 
</html>
```

i have also tried

```
<?php
if(isset($_REQUEST['font'])){
    header("location: domainpath/kothi.html");
};
?>
```

i also tried

```
<?php
header("location: domainpath/kothi.html");
?>
```

please help me to fix the problem....

Comment: It helps if you mention what is happening - are you getting an error message, warning, etc?

Comment: you should use the specific $_POST or $_GET instead of $_REQUEST

Comment: iam not getting error message if the use the last php.... when i enter the webpage it is directly redirected to domainpath/kothi.html by not submitting the form elements... hi phix can you also tell me  how to use $post /$get  method instead of $request .. please help me by compleating the code... Thank you...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have action="glitter.php", which means after submitting the form the result inputs  will be accessible into glitter.php file. So in that file you have to redirect to whatever url you wanna go.

Answer (score 3):

Is that file `glitter.php`? The redirection script should be kept in `glitter.php` as that is the page that will be loaded when you submit the form.

There are several ways to do a redirect.

via meta tag: http://webdesign.about.com/od/metataglibraries/a/aa080300a.htm

via header: http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php (you have to put `exit` after the header statement)

via Javascript: http://www.tizag.com/javascriptT/javascriptredirect.php

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, the below:

```
<?php
if(isset($_REQUEST['down'])){
    header("header("location: domainpath/kothi.html");
}
?>
```

This is incorrect, the `header` is incorrectly declared, replace `header` with the `header` below:

```
<?php
if(isset($_REQUEST['down'])){
    header("location: domainpath/kothi.html");
}
?>
```

Secondly, why `$_REQUEST`? You're making a POST, and thirdly, where is `down` coming from? You form is submitting `font` so the following is what you need:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['font'])){
    header("Location: domainpath/kothi.html");
    exit();
}
?>
```

`exit()` is added to stop the rest of the page loading too, by the way...

**Update**

It may also be best if you submitted the data too, so include the below inbetween the `<form>` tags

```
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit this form">
```

And like others point out, I hope this PHP page is called `glitter.php` so it can submit to itself...

**Update 2**

Based on your comment, then you'd want the following:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['down'])){
    header("location: domainpath/kothi.html");
    exit();
}
?>    
<html> 
<body>
    <form action="glitter.php" method="post">
        <input type="radio" name="font" value="fonts/darkcrystaloutline.ttf"/> 
        <input type="radio" name="font" value="fonts/darkcrystalout.ttf"/>
        <input type="submit" name="down" value="down">
    </form> 
</body> 
</html>
```

Though the above form will go to `glitter.php` and the `header` will **not** redirect anywhere - one has to assume that another form/page submits to this one...

Comment: iam sorry i missed one line     <input type="submit" name = "down" value = "down"> </form> </body> </html> this shopuld come on last line... and this not the "glitter.php" page

Answer (score 0):

You already asked this question once, but here add this :

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

But i have a assumption: You have to make an exit() after header() cos the rest is not allowed to be give an output. If it gives an output the header will be set to a HTML-Document and can therefore not be reset.

So try this:

```
<?php 
if(isset($_REQUEST['down']))
{
    header("location: /kothi.html");
    exit();
}
?>    
<html> 
<body>
<form action="glitter.php" method="post">
<input type="radio" name="font" value="fonts/darkcrystaloutline.ttf"/> 
<input type="radio" name="font" value="fonts/darkcrystalout.ttf"/>
</form> 
</body> 
</html>
```

BTW: I hope this form is in glitter.php and where is the input for down?
If this file is not glitter, add this in glitter:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['font'])){
    header("Location: domainpath/kothi.html");
    exit();
}
?>
```

And kill the php in the form-page.